# how to check sidekiq status without an extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

On the sidekiq wiki it says I can check the status of sidekiq by polling it.
I know when I perform delay method sidekiq will return the process id, but how do check Sidekiq to see if the id is finished processing.

I would expect some code like this:

```
if Sidekiq.check_complete?(process_id)
    puts 'Process completed'
end
```

I want to do this without any extra gems.

Comment: are you trying to check if Sidekiq is finished processing jobs, and sitting idle?  Or that the Sidekiq process is still running or not?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to see if a process if is finished processing.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment above, if you want to check if Sidekiq is done processing, the best approach is to check your queue size.  For example, using some helper functions as below..

```
 def sidekiq_stats()
   summary = Hash.new
   stats = Sidekiq::Stats.new
   summary = { processed: stats.processed,
               failed: stats.failed,
              enqueued: stats.enqueued,
              queues: stats.queues}
end


def queue_stats(queue)
  summary = Hash.new
  queue = Sidekiq::Queue.new(queue)
  summary = { size: queue.size,
              latency: queue.latency}
end
```

You can call each queue and check the size, if all queues have size 0, the Sidekiq worker is idle.